# How to display single image from custom field?

Tags: php, image, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using a custom field to upload an image to my post. I now want to display this image on the post by editing the template but struggling to find out how.

My custom field is called 'image' but all I can seem to do is display the URL of the image when I echo it.

Is there a simple way / line of code to display this image on the post?

Thanks

I used this code to get the image

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true) ?>
```

obviously it is not the best and only gets the field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just displaying it via html you can simple do this if `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true) ?>` returns a URL for the image.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true) ?>" />
```

this will use the URL you have returned to get the image.